# How to create a controller dependent on previous controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have a system which includes suggestions and then evaluations on these suggestions. So I have a `SuggestionsController` with CRUD actions. Now I want to make a `EvaluationsController` with a logical URL flow. So I'm thinking something like `/Suggestions/{suggestionId}/Evaluations/Create/{evaluationId}`. How can I implement something like that?

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I may just be using the wrong terminology, which is why I can't find any answers. The best solution I found is using something like `[RoutePrefix("Suggestions/{id}")]` on a controller level. Dunno if this is the best approach for what I'm aiming to do.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say `RoutePrefix` is the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: This isn't really what "routing" is meant to be used for as far as I know.  Your URL should point to a specific action, on a specific controller.  A URL cannot point to multiple actions/controllers.  The action it ultimately points to can take 0 or more parameters (with the ability to mark parameters as optional).  You should try to build your route so that it follows that pattern